# GoLang - How to initialize value to *time.Time

Tags: go, pointers, struct

I have a struct defined in some `device.go` file

```
type Payload struct {
    ...
    Timestamp *time.Time  `json:"timestamp,omitempty"`
    ...
}
```

Now I want to Initialize this struct in some other file and I'm trying this:

```
payload:= &device.Payload{
    ....
    Timestamp: time.Now(), // throws error
    ... //other initializations work fine
}
```

> cannot use time.Now() (value of type time.Time) as *time.Time value in
> struct literal

I want to initialize the variable as the current UTC time. I'm new to golang. How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`time.Now()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Now) returns a value of type [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time), which is not `*time.Time`.

Note that you also cannot take the address of the return values of function calls, you can't do `&time.Now()` either. For details, see [How to get the pointer of return value from function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744965/how-to-get-the-pointer-of-return-value-from-function-call/30751102#30751102)

What you may do is use a variable of type `time.Time` and take its address:

```
var t = time.Now()

payload:= &device.Payload{
    Timestamp: &t,
}
```

Another "popular" option is to create a helper function to return the address of a `time.Time` value (to which you may pass the return value of a function call directly):

```
func timePtr(t time.Time) *time.Time {
    return &t
}

payload:= &device.Payload{
    Timestamp: timePtr(time.Now()),
}
```

For details and other options, see [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481)

I assume you want a pointer because you want to allow "missing time" option, which is necessary for the `encoding/json` package to respect a "missing time" (details: [JSON omitempty With time.Time Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643815/json-omitempty-with-time-time-field/32646035#32646035)). Note that in other cases it may not be necessary to automatically turn to pointer: you may use the zero value of `time.Time` (which is a struct) to indicate the "missing time" state. To easily tell if a `time.Time` is its zero value, you may use [`Time.IsZero()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.IsZero). See related: [Idiomatic way to represent optional time.Time in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216908/idiomatic-way-to-represent-optional-time-time-in-a-struct/52217049#52217049)

Answer (score 2):

time.Now() returns a Time value, but your struct is looking for a pointer. Change your struct to

```
type Payload struct {
    ...
    Timestamp time.Time  `json:"timestamp,omitempty"`
    ...
}
```

from the docs (https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time):

> Programs using times should typically store and pass them as values, not pointers. That is, time variables and struct fields should be of type time.Time, not *time.Time.